# redis value need to convert to dict

Tags: python, redis

I use redis-py (pip install redis) to get list :

```
r_server = redis.Redis("localhost")
r_list = []
len = r_server.llen("test")
for item in range( r_server.llen("test") ):
  r_list.append(r_server.rpop("test"))
print r_list
for r in r_list:
    print r
    print type(r)
```

The result :

```
["{'a': 1, 'b': 2}", "{'a': 2, 'b': 3}"]
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
<type 'str'>
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}
<type 'str'>
```

The question the type is `string`
But I want a `dict`

Because I have to do something like this :

```
match = [dct for dct in r_list if int(dct["a"]) >=0 ]
```

It will cause error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

How can I convert it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Set the response callback for the *RPOP* command to `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
r_server.set_response_callback('RPOP', ast.literal_eval)
```

or call `ast.literal_eval` on each element of the Redis list you receive in the loop

```
from ast import literal_eval

r_list = []

for item in range(r_server.llen("test")):
    r_list.append(literal_eval(r_server.rpop("test")))
```

Of course, you can also use `eval`, but `ast.literal_eval` is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following:

```
>>> v = ["{'a': 1, 'b': 2}", "{'a': 2, 'b': 3}"]
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(v[0])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

>>> d = ast.literal_eval(v[0])
>>> d['a']
1
>>>
```

To modify to your case, you have to do the import at the beginning and instead of print r do print ast.literal_eval(r).

For your 'match' statement, I'd take a two step approach (and also check if the dictionary has the proper key).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about security, just use built-in eval().

```
v = ["{'a': 1, 'b': 2}", "{'a': 2, 'b': 3}"]
res = [eval(x) for x in v]
print(res)
```

returns

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}]
```